# ionic 5 Prevent parent scroll when child scroll reach bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a situation where when child scroll reaches bottom parent scroll takes over and starts scrolling the whole screen.

Basicall I have normal icon page with a horizontal bar at top. When user clicks on top bar a div slid downs showing the list of items covering whole screen except top bar. Because this list is loner than the screen height I have allowed vertical scrolling in div. Now the problem is when the user is scrolling inside div and reaches the bottom of the list, the background page starts scrolling up.

What I want is, inside the div scrolling should not scroll the background/parent page when user reaches bottom of the list.

code sample (in browser you will need to move mouse a bit after reaching bottom)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-forum-5-jhl2pw

Thanks